# In F#, what is the correct way to store temporary results?

Tags: math, f#, functional-programming

I have to write an Excel addin in F#, it does some pretty heavy computations in order to calibrate some curves as a first step in some User Defined Functions.

As a second step, I need re-use the representation of the universe (the curves calibrated in the first step) as an argument for other functions.

When I was doing this in a procedural language with states, I would just return a string handle on the universe which would be an object that I would store in memory. If I am doing this in F#, am I breaking the functional language paradigm ?

Is there an elegant way to do a similar thing without having to do the recalibration in the first step ? Here I am using Excel, but this is a more general question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that if you have user-defined function A and UDF B both of them require calling another function to calibrate?  If that's the case, then it sounds like you should memoize the calibration function and have A and B use the memoized function.

As a side note, you should consider disregarding typical academic implementations of memoization and consider one with [limits on the upper bound of inputs](https://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2010/07/26/limit-your-memoization-please.aspx).

As a side, side note - Excel is one of the most widely used function programming paradigms.

Comment: In my C# implementation, I have a set of functions returning strings like "CURVE1.1" "SPLINE2.1" and then I would have a way to organise them in a representation of the universe via another function which would for example return a handle "UNIVERSE1.2". Then I would pass around only this Universe handle around in the second part. I am trying to understand what is the correct way to do something similar in a functional language.